# Symfony 1.4 and wordpress integration trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony-1.4, integration

I'm making a new website using symfony 1.4 and wordpress 3.8 integration following these steps:

---

wordpress installation is located in: /web/blog

every seems to work, but when i try to install wordpress  /blog/wp-admin/install.php only a white page is shown, i think may be a problem with .htaccess who don't let me execute install.php script here is my .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [PT]

# uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
# getting no_script_name to work
#RewriteBase /

# we skip all files with .something
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
#RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

whats's wrong with my project??

Comment: `Symfony 1.4` is *super* deprecated JFYI ... use 2.x

Comment: is out of my hands, client requirement...Symfony 1.4

Comment: Check your logs or turn on error reporting in the `install.php` file.